# SSL error with rvm and ruby 2.2.2

Tags: rhel, ssl, ruby, rvm

I am getting the below error while doing a api call from one app to another:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

We are using using rvm with ruby 2.2.2 on rhel 5.x

Things which I tried to resolve the issue:

```
1] rvm reinstall 2.2.2 --disable-binary
2] curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Is there anything else I should try ?

Comment: This: https://gist.github.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5/

Comment: Tried this but did not work. Disabled ssl for now. Created file called .gemrc in the home path and added the line:

`:ssl_verify_mode: 0`